# ExpandoObject removing multiple values dynamically

Tags: c#, json, ssis

Originally I deserialize a JSON string into a dynamic type List, this worked fine until moving it to the server at which point the dynamic list stopped working. The only answer I could find is that this is not abnormal behavior for lists. [The original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321927/ssis-script-component-behavior-server-dev-machine?noredirect=1#comment62176746_37321927)

So from that I changed my dynamic list to an ExpandoObject

```
dynamic root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonstring, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

Originally in my dynamic list I called

```
    root.record.form_values.Remove("f161");
    root.record.form_values.Remove("41df");
    root.record.form_values.Remove("a228");
    root.record.Remove("changeset_id");
```

Which worked as expected removing those objects from the List which I eventually turn back into JSON and send it back to an API.

After doing some reading on ExpandoObjects I found that to delete you need to throw it out to a IDictionary in order to have the .Remove functionality.

So I did this:

```
dynamic dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)root;
```

And then replaced my code with:

```
    dict.record.form_values.Remove("f161");
    dict.record.form_values.Remove("41df");
    dict.record.form_values.Remove("a228");
    dict.record.Remove("changeset_id");
```

This resulted in the error

> 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for
> 'Remove'

So after a bit more reading I tried the following:

```
    dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)root.record.form_values.Remove("f161");
    dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)root.record.form_values.Remove("41df");
    dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)root.record.form_values.Remove("a228");
    dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)root.record.Remove("changeset_id");
```

Which resulted in the same error...

If anyone can give me a clue on where to go to from now, that would be great.

FYI The JSON Structure looks as such:

```
"{
    \"record\":{
    \"status\":\"somevalue\",
    \"form_values\":
                    {
                        \"833b\":\"somevalue\",
                        \"683b\":\"somevalue\",
                        \"c9ca\":{\"other_values\":[],\"choice_values\":[\"somevalue\"]}
                    },
    \"latitude\":somevalue,
    \"longitude\":somevalue
    }
}"
```

The original code with the DynamicList (Which worked) looks as such:

```
string jsonstring = data;

var root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonstring);
root.record.assigned_to = assignedto;
root.record.assigned_to_id = assignedtoid;
root.record.status = status.ToString();
root.record.bb42 = abudgetunit;
root.record.f694 = abudgetunitstr;
root.record.form_values.Remove("f161");
root.record.form_values.Remove("41df");
root.record.form_values.Remove("a228");
root.record.Remove("changeset_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. There are nested expando objects in the structure, and you've only converted the first one.  If you find the nested objects and convert all the way down to the form_values then it will work.

```
dynamic root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonstring, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

var rootDict =(IDictionary<string, object>) root;
var recordDict = (IDictionary<string, object>) rootDict["record"];
var formValuesDict = (IDictionary<string, object>) recordDict ["form_values"];
formValuesDict.Remove("683b");
```